# whats is wrong when i tried to insert a custom attribute programatically?

Tags: php, magento2

I have the following code :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;
    private $attributeSet;
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory, CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory; 
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory; 
    } 

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        //creating attribute set 
        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
        $data = [
            'attribute_set_name' => 'Medicamento Expira Curta', 
            'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
            'sort_order' => 200,
        ];
        $attributeSet->setData($data);
        $attributeSet->validate();
        $attributeSet->save();
        $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
        $attributeSet->save();

        //Creating products attributes
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                        'Data de fabricação',
                        [
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'label' => 'Data de fabricação', //attr name
                            'backend' => '',
                            'input' => 'date',
                            'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
                            'source' => '',
                            'required' => false,
                            'sort_order' => 5,
                            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                            'visible' => true,
                            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                            'visible_on_front' => true,
                            'attribute_set_id' => 'Expira Curta',
                    ]
                );  

                $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                        'Data de vencimento',
                        [
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'label' => 'Data de vencimento', //attr name
                            'backend' => '',
                            'input' => 'date',
                            'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
                            'source' => '',
                            'required' => false,
                            'sort_order' => 5,
                            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                            'visible' => true,
                            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                            'visible_on_front' => true,
                            'attribute_set_id' => 'Expira Curta',
                    ]
                );  

        $setup->endSetup();


    }
}
?>
```

I want to create a new attribute set called "Medicamento Expira Curta", and add 2 more attributes to it. But, when I run this code, the module change to enabled in `config.php`, and is OK in table `setup_module`, but, nothings happens, the module is not persisted, and don't pops up in the front-end and is not persisted in `eav_attribute_set` too.

What am I doing wrong? If more configuration is needed, please comment.

Comment: Which version of Magento are you actually interested in? Please delete the other version tags.

Comment: did you run setup:upgrade?

Comment: yes, but nothings happens. no error/no results.